# How to filter messages from Kafka based on headers value in AWS lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I have a message coming from Kafka to the lambda in the format:

```
{
   "eventSource":"aws:kafka",
   "eventSourceArn":"arn:aws:kafka:sa-east-1:123456789012:cluster/vpc-2priv-2pub/751d2973-a626-431c-9d4e-d7975eb44dd7-2",
   "bootstrapServers":"b-2.demo-cluster-1.a1bcde.c1.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.demo-cluster-1.a1bcde.c1.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092",
   "records":{
      "mytopic-0":[
         {
            "topic":"mytopic",
            "partition":0,
            "offset":15,
            "timestamp":1545084650987,
            "timestampType":"CREATE_TIME",
            "key":"abcDEFghiJKLmnoPQRstuVWXyz1234==",
            "value":"SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Lg==",
            "headers":[
               {
                  "headerKey":[
                     104,
                     101,
                     97,
                     100,
                     101,
                     114,
                     86,
                     97,
                     108,
                     117,
                     101
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

here in the value of headerkey the string 'headerValue' is stored. you can see it if you decode using the python script:

```
bytes(h).decode()
```

It is achieved by triggering AWS lambda function by self-managed Kafka trigger. I want to add filter messages to minimize number of not necessary runnings of heavy lambda.
So I want to add filter t the trigger: headers["headerKey"] = "headerValue" and send **only such values** to the lambda.
I found some docs on filtering:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html

it works well for filtering strings, not array because how I understand headers are always given as a list of integers and it is not clear how to it. Help me to solve the problem, please!

P.S.
I found message exmaple from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-msk.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems a "lambda filter" isn't what you want.

Every record still needs to be consumed and deserialized before deciding to continue processing or not.

If you truly want to prevent a lambda from running at all, you'll need to use some constantly running process (such as in ECS/Fargate) to consume the data, deserialize it, check the headers, then forward the necessary data to a new topic that the lambda would then trigger from

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a python code example but have a working solution with NodeJS. Maybe you can convert this to python and use?

```
const rowEventName = record.headers?.find((header: any) => 'event_type_name' in header)
  const eventType: string = Buffer.from(
    rowEventName?.event_type_name
  ).toString()
```

Above will decode the header values and persist on eventType variable.
example event:

```
{
  "eventSource": "aws:kafka",
  "records": {
    "test": [
      {
        "topic": "mytopic",
        "partition": "0",
        "offset": 1,
        "timestamp": 1545084650987,
        "timestampType": "CREATE_TIME",
        "value": "encodedvaluehere",
        "headers": [ 
          {
            "event_type_name":  [
              104,
              101,
              97,
              100,
              101,
              114,
              86,
              97,
              108,
              117,
              101
          ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```